# Unable to store sqlite3_last_insert_rowid into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using the following code to store "sqlite3_last_insert_rowid" into NSMutableArray,I am getting the rowid but nothing is stored in the array. It is giving me null.

```
  NSUInteger rowIDNum=sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(myDatabase);
        NSNumber *xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rowIDNum];
        [_rowID insertObject:xWrapped atIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"row ID array %@",[_rowID objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Could you please tell me the correct way to store rowid into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the array is not allocated, else you would get an `NSRangeException` if the array was allocated but empty (i.e. the first time you called that method).

From the [`NSMutableArray` reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject:atIndex:):

> *index*
>
> The index in the array at which to insert *anObject*. This value
>   must not be greater than the count of elements in the array.
>
> **Important**: Raises an `NSRangeException` if index is greater than the
>   number of elements in the array.

You would normally allocate the array in the class `init` method or `viewDidLoad` method, depending on what the class is.  Once you've allocated the array, use:

```
NSUInteger rowIDNum=sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(myDatabase);
[_rowID insertObject:@(rowIDNum)];
```